# i need to get data from select max value

Tags: mysql

i'm working on records that i have working on it but there is problem with my mysql is i can't get the max value of select with specific date
i have this statement to get value  :

```
select re.date, an.userAnswers , count(an.userAnswers) as countQues 
from reviwes re,answers an 
where an.userReviewsId=re.id 
and an.questionType!=5 
and re.campainId=23 
and CAST(re.date AS DATE) >= "2018-11-01 00:00:00" 
and CAST(re.date AS DATE) <= "2018-11-07 23:59:59" 
group by DATE_FORMAT(re.date, "%d-%m-%y"),an.userAnswers


+---------------------+-------------+-----------+
| date                | userAnswers | countQues |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2018-11-01 21:37:00 | 1           |         5 |
| 2018-11-01 11:53:00 | 10          |        58 |
| 2018-11-01 11:53:00 | 2           |       154 |
| 2018-11-01 14:16:00 | 3           |        79 |
| 2018-11-01 14:16:00 | 4           |        25 |
| 2018-11-01 11:53:00 | 5           |       498 |
| 2018-11-01 23:29:00 | 7           |         3 |
| 2018-11-01 20:37:00 | 8           |         5 |
| 2018-11-01 18:01:00 | 9           |         9 |
| 2018-11-02 14:06:00 | 1           |        10 |
| 2018-11-02 10:36:00 | 10          |        70 |
| 2018-11-02 10:36:00 | 2           |       193 |
| 2018-11-02 10:36:00 | 3           |       125 |
| 2018-11-02 18:13:00 | 4           |        38 |
| 2018-11-02 10:36:00 | 5           |       585 |
etc..
```

now i need to max value with the same statement, i try this :

```
select max(cast(userAnswersGet.userAnswers as int))
  ,userAnswersGet.userAnswers
  ,userAnswersGet.date
  ,userAnswersGet.countQues 
from (
    select re.date, an.userAnswers , count(an.userAnswers) as countQues 
    from reviwes re,answers an 
    where an.userReviewsId=re.id 
    and an.questionType!=5 
    and re.campainId=23 
    and CAST(re.date AS DATE) >= "2018-11-01 00:00:00" 
    and CAST(re.date AS DATE) <= "2018-11-07 23:59:59" 
    group by DATE_FORMAT(re.date, "%d-%m-%y"),an.userAnswers
) as userAnswersGet 
group by DATE_FORMAT(userAnswersGet.date, "%d-%m-%y") 
having max(cast(userAnswersGet.userAnswers as int));
```

and i expected to get output this:

```
                +---------------------+-------------+-----------+
                | date                | userAnswers | countQues |
                +---------------------+-------------+-----------+
                | 2018-11-01 11:53:00 | 10          |        58 |
                | 2018-11-02 14:06:00 | 10          |        70 |
```

Comment: Please take a few moments and fix your formatting.  Currently, your question is illegible.  Add four or more spaces to each line of code.

Comment: done sry for that

Comment: You might also want to add the expected output to your question.  @scaisEdge thanks for the edit.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: With respect, I suggest you study how to use GROUP BY. Your use of it doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: done added the expected output

Comment: Your expected output doesn't make sense. Nothing in the second row is a max value

Comment: @JaredC sorry for that fixed i was hurry to set the output !

Comment: Why doing a date_format in Group by ? o_O

Comment: @DanielE. i need to get by date only not with minutes ! :)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score -1):

**1 - Quick reminder:** 
When you use a Group by, you must put all the columns from the select if it's not an aggregative function. 
Example :

```
SELECT A, Max(A) FROM MyTable GROUP BY A
```

2- This query is correct but I am not sure of what you want to do :

```
select max(userAnswersGet.userAnswers) as 'userAnswers'      
  ,userAnswersGet.date
  ,userAnswersGet.countQues 
from (
    select re.date, an.userAnswers , count(an.userAnswers) as countQues 
    from reviwes re,answers an 
    where an.userReviewsId=re.id 
    and an.questionType!=5 
    and re.campainId=23 
    and CAST(re.date AS DATE) >= "2018-11-01 00:00:00" 
    and CAST(re.date AS DATE) <= "2018-11-07 23:59:59" 
    group by DATE_FORMAT(re.date, "%d-%m-%y"),an.userAnswers
) as userAnswersGet 
group by DATE_FORMAT(userAnswersGet.date, "%d-%m-%y"),  userAnswersGet.countQues;
```